# Application.Match mismatch error 13 - How to resolve?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-match

I have been working on some code that goes through and tries to find "New Muted Price" or "New Opposed Price". If that is not found during the array iteration, it comes up with a

> Mismatch error run code 13

I know this is because it did not find it, but how do I just get it to skip past the error and continue with the code? I have tried

```
if not iserror (PriceCol = Application.Match("New Opposed Price", rng, 0)) then but it is still showing the mismatch error.
```

The portions of the code where the error comes up is:

```
 PriceCol = Application.Match("New Opposed Price", rng, 0)
```

and

```
pricecol2 = Application.Match("New Muted Price", rng, 0)
```

Does anyone have some advise on how to resolve this issue?

```
Sub WIP()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsMain As Worksheet
    Dim wsLookup As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim rFind1 As Range
    Dim rFind2 As Range
    Dim rFind3 As Range
    Dim MyArray As Variant
    Dim LookupHeaders As Variant
    Dim LookupHeaders2 As Variant
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim PriceCol As Long
    Dim pricecol2 As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Long
     Dim LastColumn2 As Long
       Dim LastColumn3 As Long
     Dim LastColumn4 As Long
    Dim IndexCol As Long

     'Unformatted Price Row
  Sheets("Consolidate List").Select
    LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Columns("H:H").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Columns("J:N").Delete
    Columns("J:J").Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    Range("H2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "New Price"
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 22
         Range("H3:H" & LR).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-7],'Connect Report'!C[-7]:C[-6],2,FALSE)"
         ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Resize(Rows.Count - 2).Offset(2).Select
 Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Range("I2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Difference"
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 22
    Range("I3:I" & LR).Formula = "=IF(OR(OR(RC[-2]="""",RC[-1]="""",RC[-1]=""x"",)),"""",RC[-1]-RC[-2])"
         ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Resize(Rows.Count - 2).Offset(2).Select
 Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
     Sheets("Consolidate List").Select
    Set wsMain = wb.ActiveSheet
    Set wsLookup = wb.Sheets("Connect Report")     '<-- Change to correct sheet name for the Lookup sheet
    LR = wsMain.Cells(wsMain.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    MyArray = Array("US", "SPAIN", "California")
    LookupHeaders = Array("TTIER", "Time333", "Round6")
  LookupHeaders2 = Array("TELLER5", "Fly7", "Mine4")

    For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
        With wsMain.Rows(1)
            Set rFind1 = .Find(What:=MyArray(i), LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not rFind1 Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = rFind1.Offset(1).Resize(, 8)
                PriceCol = Application.Match("New Opposed Price", rng, 0)
                LastColumn = rFind1.Column + PriceCol
                If wsMain.Cells(rng.Row, LastColumn) <> "New Opposed Price" Then
                    wsMain.Columns(LastColumn).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                    wsMain.Cells(rng.Row, LastColumn).Value = "New Opposed Price"
                    wsMain.Cells(rng.Row, LastColumn).Interior.ColorIndex = 22
                    LastColumn2 = LastColumn + 1
                     wsMain.Columns(LastColumn2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                    wsMain.Cells(rng.Row, LastColumn2).Value = "Difference"
                    wsMain.Cells(rng.Row, LastColumn2).Interior.ColorIndex = 22

                Set rFind2 = wsLookup.Rows(1).Find(LookupHeaders(i), wsLookup.Range("A1"), xlValues, xlWhole)
                If Not rFind2 Is Nothing Then
                    IndexCol = rFind2.Column
                    wsMain.Cells(rng.Row + 1, LastColumn).Resize(LR - 2).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A" & rng.Row + 1 & ",'Connect Report'!$A:$AL," & IndexCol & ",FALSE)"

                      wsMain.Cells(rng.Row + 1, LastColumn2).Resize(LR - 2).Formula = "=IF(OR(OR(RC[-2]="""",RC[-1]="""",RC[-1]=""x"",)),"""",RC[-1]-RC[-2])"
                              Else
                    MsgBox "Excel could not find " & LookupHeaders(i) & " in the lookup table."
                End If

                Set rng2 = rFind1.Offset(1).Resize(, 8)
                pricecol2 = Application.Match("New Muted Price", rng, 0)
                LastColumn3 = rFind1.Column + pricecol2
                   If wsMain.Cells(rng.Row, LastColumn3) <> "New Muted Price" Then
                    wsMain.Columns(LastColumn3).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                    wsMain.Cells(rng2.Row, LastColumn3).Value = "New Muted Price"
                    wsMain.Cells(rng2.Row, LastColumn3).Interior.ColorIndex = 22
                    LastColumn4 = LastColumn3 + 1
                      wsMain.Columns(LastColumn4).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                    wsMain.Cells(rng2.Row, LastColumn4).Value = "Difference"
                    wsMain.Cells(rng2.Row, LastColumn4).Interior.ColorIndex = 22
                End If

                      Set rFind3 = wsLookup.Rows(1).Find(LookupHeaders2(i), wsLookup.Range("A1"), xlValues, xlWhole)
                If Not rFind3 Is Nothing Then
                    IndexCol = rFind3.Column
                    wsMain.Cells(rng2.Row + 1, LastColumn3).Resize(LR - 2).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A" & rng2.Row + 1 & ",'Connect Report'!$A:$AL," & IndexCol & ",FALSE)"

                      wsMain.Cells(rng2.Row + 1, LastColumn4).Resize(LR - 2).Formula = "=IF(OR(OR(RC[-2]="""",RC[-1]="""",RC[-1]=""x"",)),"""",RC[-1]-RC[-2])"

                    Else
                    MsgBox "Excel could not find " & LookupHeaders2(i) & " in the lookup table."
                End If
                End If
             End If
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You should declare both variables `As Variant` because they will not be numbers if the value is not found, and add If clauses to check that a number is returned before proceeding.

Comment: @SRJ, would it just be if pricecol is not nothing then ... after the pricecol line?

Comment: @Nic no. Pricecol can't be nothing, because it's not an object.

Comment: Hold a second, I have an answer.

Comment: Try `IsNumeric`.

Comment: Also read up on how to avoid Select and Activate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track using `Application.Match` (which can return an `Error` object) versus `WorksheetFunction.Match` (which always raises the error).

But since your `PriceCol` and `PriceCol2` variables are strongly typed as `Long`, you'll get a Mismatch error.

Use another throwaway variable to handle the return:

```
Dim matchVal as Variant
matchVal = Application.Match("New Muted Price", rng, 0)
If Not IsError(matchVal) Then
    PriceCol2 = matchVal
    ...


Else
    ' if there is no match, you may need to do something else here.

End If
```

Alternatively, you could use the `Range.Find` method:

```
If Not rng.Find("New Muted Price") Is Nothing
    PriceCol2 = Application.Match("New Muted Price", rng, 0)
Else
    ...
```

Comment: No. If you have a new question, ask a new question. Don't keep making ninja edits to already-answered questions. By editing your question as such, you've destroyed the original question, and this answer is now not actually an answer to the question you originally asked.

Comment: @Nic please don't chameleonize your questions like this. If your code works as intended and you want to make it more efficient, head over to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: oh sorry, I wasnt aware of this, will take it there. thanks!

Comment: I rolled the question back to its previous state. ask a new question for your future problems -- asking is free, you know :D